# Android EditText has extra padding

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have the following layout in my app:
[image]

As you can see, there is extra padding in both `EditText`s. The one that says "infinity" has slightly less padding due to `android:includeFontPadding="false"`. I also set `android:paddingTop="0dp"` on that one and it made it smaller but the padding is still there. How can i remove this? I want it to be sized down to the red rectangle (similar to the way "Search range" is sized).

**Edit**

Here is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search_range_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search range:"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/search_range_title"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_range_start"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_purple"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="to"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_range_end"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:text="infinity"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/infinity_button"
            style="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_clear"
            android:src="@drawable/infinity"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit 2**

Layout and XML modified.

**Edit 3**

The issue seems to be related to the background because when setting `android:background="@null"`, the bounds are the way that i wanted and there is no extra padding.

Comment: post your xml..

Comment: @JohnJoe XML posted.

Comment: Remove `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`, what you get ?

Comment: Removing `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` has no effect.

Comment: I'm more interested in the top and bottom padding, but i tried it and it just made the box smaller, without removing the padding.

Comment: The top and bottom padding can only be reduced by using negative values for padding `android:paddingLeft="-2dp"`. This is due to the type of the font itself.
The right and left spaces can be adjusted by changing the value of the `weightSum` and adding an appropriate `layout_weight` value for each child view of the `LinearLayout`. Otherwise, just use a `RelativeLayout` instead

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inversing the padding for edit text.

```
<EditText

abdroid:padding="-1dp"
```